# ХешТеги в комментариях заменять на ссылку

Tags: php, javascript

Хотелось бы узнать такую штукенцию. При добавление нового комментария в поле можно вставлять "[@123](/users/2623/123)" или "#123", где 123 - это идентификатор пользователя или статьи. А как же преобразовать эти теги в ссылку, когда сообщение обрабатывается и даже код ссылки становится текстом. 
(P.S. Что-то типо как в Твиттер или даже как на ХешКоде).
P.P.S. "ХешКод", Вы реализовали здесь такую функцию, не подскажите как? Был бы Вам признателен.
Какие есть догадки? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

1) Заменяем все подстроки, вида /@(d+)/ на некую конструкцию, которая ловит наведение мыши, например:

```
<a
  href = "comment.php?id=ID"
  onmouseover = "showComment(this, ID);" 
  onmouseout = "hideComment(this);"
>Комментарий №ID</a>
```

2) Пишем функции показа/скрытия комментария:

```
function showComment( el, id ){
  //AJAX запрос на получение содержимого комментария ID = id
  //Добавление элемента с комментарием в DOM где-то рядом с el
  //Оставляем ссылку в el на созданный
}

function hideComment( el ){
  //Удаляем элемент с комментарием из DOM
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.